# Delete lines shorter than a certain length and the one above it (remove short sequences in a FASTA file)

Tags: sed, bioinformatics, fasta

I have a file containing the following text:

```
>seq1
GAAAT
>seq2
CATCTCGGGA
>seq3
GAC
>seq4
ATTCCGTGCC
```

If a line that doesn't start with ">" is shorter than 5 characters, I want to delete it and the one right above it.

Expected output:

```
>seq2
CATCTCGGGA
>seq4
ATTCCGTGCC
```

I have tried `sed -r '/^.{,5}$/d'`, but it also deletes the lines with ">".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a GNU sed, you can use

```bash
sed -E '/>/N;/\n[^>].{0,4}$/d'
```

*Details*:

- `/>/` - finds lines with `>` (if it must be at the start, add `^` before `>`)
- `N` - reads the line and appends it to the pattern space with a leading newline
- `\n[^>].{0,4}$` - a newline, a char other than a `>` (as the first char should not be `>`) and then zero to four chars till end of the string
- `d` removes the value in pattern space.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/awx7Ux):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='>seq1
GAAAT
>seq2
CATCTCGGGA
>seq3
GAC
>seq4
ATTCCGTGCC'
sed -E '/>/N;/\n[^>].{0,4}$/d' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
>seq2
CATCTCGGGA
>seq4
ATTCCGTGCC
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '/^>/N;/\n[A-Z]\{6,\}$/!d' input_file
>seq2
CATCTCGGGA
>seq4
ATTCCGTGCC
```

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, with `awk` you could try following `awk` code. Simple explanation would be, if a line starts from `>` then setting variable `val` with value of current line and `next` will skip all further statements from here. Then if a line doesn't start from `>` if length of current line is greater than `5` then printing val ORS and current line.

```
awk '/^>/{val=$0;next} length($0)>5{print val ORS $0}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not reinvent the wheel. Use common bioinformatics tools for that, such as `seqtk` or `seqkit`. Among other things, these tools can handle multiline FASTA sequences. Examples:

```
seqtk seq -L 5 in.fasta > out.fasta

seqkit seq -m 5 in.fa > out.fasta
```

To install these tools, use `conda`, specifically `miniconda`, for example:

```
conda create --channel bioconda --name seqtk seqtk
conda activate seqtk
# ... use seqtk here ...
conda deactivate
```

**REFERENCES:**

Remove sequences <300 bases from FASTA file: https://www.biostars.org/p/329680/
`seqtk`: https://github.com/lh3/seqtk
`seqkit`: https://bioinf.shenwei.me/seqkit/
`conda`: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/index.html

Answer (score 1):

very inelegant solution just to get it to work =(

> ```
> {m,g}awk ' !_<NR && 5 < length($(NF-=_==$NF))\
>                  &&                           \
>          ($!NF =">seq" $!_ ORS $+NF)^_'  FS='[ \t\n]+' OFS='\n' RS='\n*>seq'
> ```

```
>seq2
CATCTCGGGA
>seq4
ATTCCGTGCC
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Biopython for this. It makes FASTA processing convenient.

```
'''
Biopython version: 1.79
'''
from Bio import SeqIO
for seq_record in SeqIO.parse("input.fasta", "fasta"):
    if len(seq_record.seq)>=5:
        print(">",seq_record.id)
        print(seq_record.seq)
```